# how to get image date and time (Created Data) from firebase storage in android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I want to get image date and time under the Created heading from firebase storage. Is there any way to get it? I have checked many tutorials but haven't find my answer yet.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The file creation time is available in the [`StorageMetadata`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageMetadata) object. You can [get the metadata for a file](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/file-metadata#get_file_metadata) with:

> ```
> forestRef.getMetadata().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<StorageMetadata>() {
>   @Override
>   public void onSuccess(StorageMetadata storageMetadata) {
>     // Metadata now contains the metadata for 'images/forest.jpg'
>     System.out.println(storageMetadata.getCreationTimeMillis());
>   }
> })
> ```